# Avoiding "Ghost" Clients in a Fluid DataObject

Tags: fluid-framework

One of the weird things that I've noticed is that when you try to do a "multi-cursor" sort of thing with the Fluid Framework is that you might try to model each user with the runtime's Audience or Quorum (i.e. in a `DataObject`, running `this.runtime.getAudience()` or `this.runtime.getQuorum()`). You can track users entering/leaving with

- `audience.on("addMember", (clientId, details) => { /*...*/ })`
- `audience.on("removeMember", clientId => { /*...*/ })`.

This often leads to a lot of basic/naive examples with "ghost" cursors, and you can actually see it in the Fluid playground examples. I guess I have two questions

Are `IAudiences`/`IQuorums` too raw of an abstraction? Is there any way to determine whether an added client is an actual "person"?

I see that `audience.on("addMember")` provides a `details` argument to its callback, so that seems likely, but it's not well-documented at this point.

Comment: There is work to improve the IAudience & IQuorum. There's an ongoing project to improve the Audience api surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Ghost" Clients in a Fluid Framework container are [summarizers](https://fluidframework.com/docs/advanced/summarizer/) or other non-human connected clients. These summarizer clients have been automatically added to summarize the current state of the container.

The current Audience & Quorum API surfaces are *definitely* raw. They're an active area of improvement in the Fluid Framework codebase. ([An early PR was opened today.](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/pull/5537))

The following method demonstrates how you'd get all the human users with the current API surface. You can tell that they're "non-human" because the human clients are labeled "interactive".

```js
function getHumans() {
    const allMembers: IAudience = this.runtime.getAudience().getMembers();
    const justHumans = new Map<string, IClient>();

    allMembers.forEach((value, key) => {
        if (value.details.capabilities.interactive) {
            justHumans.set(key, value);
        }
    })
    return justHumans;
}
```

A little background information on why we have separate summarizing clients...

While a human client could generate a summary, separating out the summarizing client makes it easier to host the summarizer on a different process (service worker) or on a node process in the cloud.

Summaries are reasonably well documented [here](https://fluidframework.com/docs/advanced/summarizer/), but they're an abstraction on top of the op stream to improve loading times.